# My factorial and power functions output a number in the millions when it shouldn't and I don't know how to fix it(in c)

Tags: c, function, factorial

> I am trying to write a sort of calculator program and i can get everything but my factorial and power functions to work. They output a number in the millions no matter how small the number is and i don't see a problem with the code. (I just started learning C recently so assume the extent of my knowledge is everything in this code)

```
int iFactorial(num1){//needs help returns a number in the millions no matter what

    int i, factorial=1;
    printf("Enter a positive number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    for(i=1; i<=num1; i++)
            factorial*=i;
            printf("The factorial is %i", &factorial);
    return 0;

}
int fPower(num1,num2){//needs help, same as above
    int i, number = 1;
    printf("Enter the number you want to raise to a power: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter the exponent: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    for(i=0; i<num2; i++)
        number*=num1;
        printf("%d to the %d equals %d", &num1, &num2, &number);
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: If that's all that doesn't work, why are you burdening the post and us with everything else? Please read about how you should create a [mcve].

Comment: Enable all compile warnings to speed problem solving.

Answer (score 3):

You are using & in the print statement that prints the address of the variable used.
Correct the statements in their respective function as follows :

```
printf("The factorial is %i", factorial);

printf("%d to the %d equals %d", num1, num2, number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `printf` for the factorial and power cases are mal-formed, you are passing the arguments by pointer; you need to pass them by value.

After that, you'll realise quickly that you'll overflow the `int` type in the factorial and power cases. An `int` in general is only good up to and including `7!` in truly portable C++. Consider using an `unsigned long long`, which will give you values up to and including `21!`. Use `"%ull"` for an `unsigned long long` in the formatter.

Finally, pass the *types* explicitly to your functions in C: your style has been explicitly disallowed since C99.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong format specifiers to `printf` to print the results, and you're not passing the actual values you want to print:

```
printf("The factorial is %i", &factorial);
```

You're passing in the address of `factorial` instead of its value, so it's printing that instead.  Just pass the result directly instead of its address:

```
printf("The factorial is %i", factorial);
```